# Why do I get the error "Expected type parameter, found integral variable"?

Tags: generics, rust

I am getting familiar with Rust generics, but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn frequency<T: Ord + Clone>(vec: &Vec<T>) -> BTreeMap<T, u32> {
    let mut movie_reviews = BTreeMap::new();
    let mut vec_ = Vec::new();
    vec.push(1);
    movie_reviews
}
```

I have no clue why it expected type `T`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:6:14
  |
6 |     vec.push(1);
  |              ^ expected type parameter, found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `T`
             found type `{integer}`
```

Comment: Can you provide your reasoning that led you to think that you could push a number into a vector of `T`? This `T` is universal in the context of this function, it could be anything that obeys the given constraints.

Comment: Side note, [&Vec<T> as a function parameter is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/1233251), you can do `&[T]` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have no clue why it expected type `T`

It's expecting a value of type `T` because you are trying to push a value into a `Vec<T>`.

The problem is that the only information you have given the compiler about `T` is that it is `Ord + Clone` - but neither of those traits say that `1` is a value of `T`. There is a trait called `One` in the `num` crate, which provides this:

```
extern crate num; // 0.2.0

use num::One;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn frequency<T>(vec: &mut Vec<T>) -> BTreeMap<T, u32> 
where
    T: Ord + Clone + One,
{
    let mut movie_reviews = BTreeMap::new();
    vec.push(T::one());
    movie_reviews
}
```

---

As others have commented, your code has one or two other issues, which I won't address here since this will fix the error that you have asked about.

Answer (score 2):

In you code, you have two similarly names variables `vec` from the function definition that is an immutable reference to a `Vec<T>` (with `T: Ord+Clone`) and `vec_` with is a `Vec<_>` (I've put an `_` here to show that you let the compiler infer the type)

You cannot push `1` in `vec`: first you only have an immuable reference to it and push would need a mutable one, second `vec` is is a `Vec` of `T` which in that case can be pretty much everything that implements `Ord` and `Clone` and the compiler can't ensure you can push an integer in it.

You can however push `1` in `vec_` and the compiler will infer the type of it to be a `Vec` of integers